# how to retrieve all visible table section header views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

is there a way to get all the section header views that are visible?

something similar to UITableView's visibleCells instance method..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem with using indexPathsForVisibleRows is that it doesn't include sections without any rows. To get all visible section, including empty sections you have to check the rect of the section and compare it to the contentOffset of the table.

You also have to pay attention to the difference between plain style with floating sections and grouped style without floating sections.

I made a category that support this calculation:

```
@interface UITableView (VisibleSections)

// Returns an array of NSNumbers of the current visible section indexes
- (NSArray *)indexesOfVisibleSections;
// Returns an array of UITableViewHeaderFooterView objects of the current visible section headers
- (NSArray *)visibleSections;

@end

@implementation UITableView (VisibleSections)

- (NSArray *)indexesOfVisibleSections {
    // Note: We can't just use indexPathsForVisibleRows, since it won't return index paths for empty sections.
    NSMutableArray *visibleSectionIndexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.numberOfSections];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.numberOfSections; i++) {
        CGRect headerRect;
        // In plain style, the section headers are floating on the top, so the section header is visible if any part of the section's rect is still visible.
        // In grouped style, the section headers are not floating, so the section header is only visible if it's actualy rect is visible.
        if (self.style == UITableViewStylePlain) {
            headerRect = [self rectForSection:i];
        } else {
            headerRect = [self rectForHeaderInSection:i];
        }
        // The "visible part" of the tableView is based on the content offset and the tableView's size.
        CGRect visiblePartOfTableView = CGRectMake(self.contentOffset.x, self.contentOffset.y, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(visiblePartOfTableView, headerRect)) {
            [visibleSectionIndexes addObject:@(i)];
        }
    }
    return visibleSectionIndexes;
}

- (NSArray *)visibleSections {
    NSMutableArray *visibleSects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.numberOfSections];
    for (NSNumber *sectionIndex in self.indexesOfVisibleSections) {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *sectionHeader = [self headerViewForSection:sectionIndex.intValue];
        [visibleSects addObject:sectionHeader];
    }

    return visibleSects;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 13):

I really liked @adamsiton's solution and I ended up translating it to swift. Here it is, FYI.

I called the file UITableView+VisibleSections.swift

```
import UIKit

public extension UITableView {

    var indexesOfVisibleSections: [Int] {
        // Note: We can't just use indexPathsForVisibleRows, since it won't return index paths for empty sections.
        var visibleSectionIndexes = [Int]()

        for i in 0..<numberOfSections {
            var headerRect: CGRect?
            // In plain style, the section headers are floating on the top, so the section header is visible if any part of the section's rect is still visible.
            // In grouped style, the section headers are not floating, so the section header is only visible if it's actualy rect is visible.
            if (self.style == .plain) {
                headerRect = rect(forSection: i)
            } else {
                headerRect = rectForHeader(inSection: i)
            }
            if headerRect != nil {
                // The "visible part" of the tableView is based on the content offset and the tableView's size.
                let visiblePartOfTableView: CGRect = CGRect(x: contentOffset.x, y: contentOffset.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
                if (visiblePartOfTableView.intersects(headerRect!)) {
                    visibleSectionIndexes.append(i)
                }
            }
        }
        return visibleSectionIndexes
    }

    var visibleSectionHeaders: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView] {
        var visibleSects = [UITableViewHeaderFooterView]()
        for sectionIndex in indexesOfVisibleSections {
            if let sectionHeader = headerView(forSection: sectionIndex) {
                visibleSects.append(sectionHeader)
            }
        }

        return visibleSects
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexesOfVisibleSections` may be written in more compact code:
https://pastebin.com/CHTb1C8w

Answer (score 4):

For a plain style table, you can get the visible rows. From those, get the set of visible sections. And from that, get the section header views from the table.

```
NSArray *visibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSMutableIndexSet *sections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visibleRows) {
    [sections addIndex:indexPath.section];
}

NSMutableArray *headerViews = [NSMutableArray array];
[sections enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    UIView *view = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:idx];
    [headerViews addObject:view];
}];
```

Note: code not tested - may contain typos. This won't work 100% for a grouped style table.

Comment: @PeterLapisu True but you shouldn't be showing a section header for a section with no rows so this won't be a problem.

Comment: depends on the case, i just encountered such a situation :))

Comment: Empty sections is an important scenario. I added an answer that handles it.

Comment: Small correction :  `NSArray *headerViews = [NSArray array];` this should replace with `NSMutableArray *headerViews = [NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 2):

The solution by Benjamin Wheeler is a great Swift solution. I fixed an issue in it due to new Swift syntax, and modified it to match the .visibleCells property provided by the default UITableView implementation.

```
extension UITableView {

    /// The table section headers that are visible in the table view. (read-only)
    ///
    /// The value of this property is an array containing UITableViewHeaderFooterView objects, each representing a visible cell in the table view.
    ///
    /// Derived From: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/31029960/5191100](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31029960/5191100)
    var visibleSectionHeaders: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView] {
        get {
            var visibleSects = [UITableViewHeaderFooterView]()

            for sectionIndex in indexesOfVisibleSections() {
                if let sectionHeader = self.headerViewForSection(sectionIndex) {
                    visibleSects.append(sectionHeader)
                }
            }

            return visibleSects
        }
    }

    private func indexesOfVisibleSections() -> Array<Int> {
        // Note: We can't just use indexPathsForVisibleRows, since it won't return index paths for empty sections.
        var visibleSectionIndexes = Array<Int>()

        for (var i = 0; i < self.numberOfSections; i++) {
            var headerRect: CGRect?
            // In plain style, the section headers are floating on the top,
            // so the section header is visible if any part of the section's rect is still visible.
            // In grouped style, the section headers are not floating,
            // so the section header is only visible if it's actual rect is visible.
            if (self.style == .Plain) {
                headerRect = self.rectForSection(i)
            } else {
                headerRect = self.rectForHeaderInSection(i)
            }

            if headerRect != nil {
                // The "visible part" of the tableView is based on the content offset and the tableView's size.
                let visiblePartOfTableView: CGRect = CGRect(
                    x: self.contentOffset.x,
                    y: self.contentOffset.y,
                    width: self.bounds.size.width,
                    height: self.bounds.size.height
                )

                if (visiblePartOfTableView.intersects(headerRect!)) {
                    visibleSectionIndexes.append(i)
                }
            }
        }

        return visibleSectionIndexes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `UITableView` extension that gives you the `visibleHeaderViews` based on @OhadM answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525595/5058116), but which checks on potential `nil` values.

```
extension UITableView {

    /// The section header views that are visible in the table view.
    var visibleHeaderViews: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView] {

        var headerViews = [UITableViewHeaderFooterView]()

        guard let indexPaths = indexPathsForVisibleRows else { return headerViews }

        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            if let headerView = headerView(forSection: indexPath.section) {
                headerViews.append(headerView)
            }
        }

        return headerViews

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think you set the `cell.tag` to the current section (`indexPath.section`) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and use the `visibleCells` method as you described and `headerViewForSection`.

Answer (score 1):

to get the current visible sections, u could get it by checking the current visible cells indexpath section, so this function could return to u the visible sections

```
- (NSArray *)indexesOfVisibleSections {

    NSMutableArray *visibleSections = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (UITableViewCell * cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        if (![visibleSections containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].section]]) {
            [visibleSections addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].section]];
        }
    }

    return visibleSections;
}
```

And to access section view , u can use

```
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Comment: doesn't account for a header that contains no cells

Comment: @kgaidis have u tested it ? logic here that it gets the visible cell section , regardless to it's type, so if u got 3 sections, each one got 1 row, then it check the visible rows array and it get those rows sections and adds it to array of visible sections, it has nothing to do with section header type , view or cell

Comment: "Each one got 1 row." That's where it fails. A section can exist, with a header view visible, that has no cells. If a section has no cells, then it won't be part of `visibleCells`, which is what this algorithm is entirely relying on.

Comment: i see, so the logic adamsiton wrote seems more logical :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) documentation gives us the [indexPathsForVisibleRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614885-indexpathsforvisiblerows) and combining it with map gives us the array we need:

```
tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows.map{ tableView.headerView(forSection: $0.section) }
```

map returns the array of our visible headers-in-section.

Comment: Good stuff here, but it can crash with `nil` (check my answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+**
Clean and simple, without duplicities:

```
extension UITableView {

    var visibleHeaderViews: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView] {
        guard let visibleSectionsIndexPaths = indexPathsForVisibleRows?.compactMap({ $0.section }) else { return [] }

        return Set(visibleSectionsIndexPaths).compactMap { headerView(forSection: $0) }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does not work if the sections are empty (no rows), as indexPathsForVisibleRows property name indicates.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers turn out to be overly complicated. All you need to do is call `headerView(forSection:)` in a loop. It will return nil for header views that are not visible.

However, there is a catch: Your header views *have* to inherit from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for this to work (which they technically should anyway, but everything except this works even if they don't so you can easily miss this.)

Once you have your class inheriting correctly, you can just do this:

```
for section in 0 ..< tableView.numberOfSections {
    guard let header = tableView.headerView(forSection: section) as? CustomHeaderView else { continue }
    header.update(...)
}
```