# How to make a nested table ( multiple level sections ) on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The structure of data likes following code :

```
var list = [
    "School A" : [
        "Class A" : [
            "student A",
            "student B",
            "student C"
        ],
        "Class B" : [
            "student A",
            "student B",
            "student C"
        ]
    ],
    "School B" : [
        "Class A" : [
            "student A",
            "student B",
            "student C"
        ],
        "Class B" : [
            "student A",
            "student B",
            "student C"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I want to show it with an `UITableView` like this :

```
Section header : school
    Section header : class
        Student
        ...
    Section header : class
        Student
        ...
    ...
Section header : school
    ...
...
```

And I hope both `Section header : school` and `Section header : class` can float above rows of section while scrolling.

If there isn't anyway to do this, is there anyway to listen the event while one `Section header : class` start to float? Then I want to add school name to the floating class section header.

Comment: you can create table in main tableview's cell.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Yes I tried. But in that way, the tableView in main tableview's cell only can scroll in the cell. If I set the cell height equal the inner table height and set scrollEnabled = false, the section header of inner table cannot float at the top any more.

Comment: Any success? Stuck on similar issue

Comment: @LCB managed to find a way to make it work? cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make it such that both school and class are on tableview's section header (same level). The difference will be school's sections always have 0 rows and class sections have students as rows. The tricky part will be in setting the datasource.

> is there anyway to listen the event while one Section header : class start to float？Then I wanna add school name to the floating class section header.

I've done something similar by [checking visible section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15204328/6543229) on top part of the screen. On floating header tableviews the header is always visible when any part of the section is visible so checking which sections are visible is enough to know which header is visible. I'm checking it continuously on tableview's `-scrollviewDidScroll` delegate method which I wouldn't recommend unless you have no other options

Comment: thanks. If I set school sections have only section header without any rows, header of sections cannot float while scrolling.